Can't Install Windows 11 on unsupported CPU with the latest 24H2 ISO
I have a spare laptop (Lenovo G550) and want to install Windows 11 24h2 on this unsupported device for fun as the device is no longer used for work. Before starting a new post here, I read two posts on superuser and tried the popular Rufus tool but no luck. The error message says:

This PC's processor doesn't support a critical feature of (PopCnt).
This PC's processor doesn't support a critical feature of (SSE4.2).

I also tried the "setupprep.exe /product server" trick in Command Prompt. Unfortunately, the same error message shows up again. Is there any other workaround available to install Windows 11 on unsupported CPU?

A quick google suggests that even if it works, it would leave your system unbootable.  It looks like the installer is doing its best to keep you from shooting yourself in the foot.

I can see a lot of folks running Windows 1 1 on unsupported devices. By the way, it is not a working machine.

Your using the wrong trick

Setup.exe /product server is the correct workaround. However, your processor does not support the required x86 extensions, there isn’t a workaround for that particular change only having an “unsupported” processor that does support those x86 extensions but are not officially supported like a 4th Intel Core Processor.

I think there's a few things here. I've installed windows 11 on an unsupported system before and there's both 'soft' and 'hard' blockers.
The processor you're trying to install this on is likely a T4200,  a T4500 or something of that era  - Its about 8-10 generations older than supported, that likely shipped with vista or XP. Its old and lacks some things 24H2 was compiled for.
I think a short version of what's going on is the installer is trying strangely hard to not leave your system in an unbootable state.
Rufus does a few things - it runs a set of official bypasses MS has put in place for more technical users and sysadmins - its documented in this issues thread and runs a patched installer for an in place update.
Now, what it dosen't do is patches that are not in any way supported by MS, and the popcnt and SSE 4.2 requirements are a hard requirement. Even if the /product server bypass worked, you'd be stuck in a reboot cycle according to this twitter thread, since the latest builds of windows are compiled requiring these instructions.
TPM 2.0 not being there, or running a CPU older than an arbitrary cut off can be worked around. Missing a fundamental CPU instruction the kernel and OS relies on can't be.

I'd also add, that machine would run linux quite well.

The error clearly shows the CPU is not supported and it is too old to be bypassed with the normal hacks, especially for the latest Windows 11 24H2. The Lenovo G550 laptop is powered by 2.3GHz Intel Pentium Dual-Core T4500, which was launched on 2010. Basically every Intel Core i3, i5, i7, and AMD FX and Ryzen CPU supports SSE4.2 and PopCnt well.
You won't fix this with any hacks, new Windows 11 24H2is compiled with these CPU instructions in use, so it won't boot on these very old CPU. You have to upgrade the CPU in order to install Windows 11 24H2 on unsupported CPU. Or you can try an old Windows 11 version such as 21H2 without any hardware upgrade.

Another way is to use the Parallels app if your PC has enough RAM so you can share enough to the Parallels app, then it will sort out things as it offers virtual TPU

Its not a TPU issue - in theory if you could fully emulate a supported CPU you could possibly run that build, at the cost of very poor performance and massive overhead.
